# how to connect ms mql and android?what all i need in my system for using ms _ql

Tags: android, sql-server-2008

i am trying to make an android app which use ms sql.i know how to use mysql.Also can anyone tell me the installation details of ms sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MS SQL Server Installation you can follow the steps provided by Microsoft itself.

[Install SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143219.aspx)

For using localy just use [jtds jar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/jtds/1.3.1/) in your project with the following programs.

```
     String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
     String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.168.38/Check;instance=SQLEXPRESS;";
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            Log.i("driver", "driver work finish");
            Log.i("conn", "con starts");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
            Log.i("con", "OPEN");

            if(conn != null){
                Toast.makeText(SqlserverConnection.this, "Connect Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 Log.w("Connection","open");
                    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from [dbo].[Regester]");

                    String result = "";
                       ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();


                    while(rs.next()) {
                        result += rsmd.getColumnName(1) + ": " + rs.getInt(1) + "\t";
                        result += rsmd.getColumnName(2) + ": " + rs.getString(2) + "\t";
                        result += rsmd.getColumnName(3) + ": " + rs.getString(3) + "\n";
                    }

       conn.close();

     }
```

If you want to use it like a server then you have to create some webservices which will help you to connect the android application with the server database and doing some CUID operations.

Comment: thanks..can u guide me about the loaction where i have to store webservice files if i am using remote sql server.actually i need to test my app locally,i dono wer to store webservice file

Comment: .if i use webservice then where is the location i have t store webservice file , if i want to test locally, to know whether app is able to acces database or not??is tat inside inetpub/wwwuroot/??